# Should this file be loaded as a valid .js file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, content-type

I am trying to create a PHP file that the browser will see as a js file, and are using the content-type header. But there's something not working, even though. So my question is, should this be interpreted as a valid .js file?:

```
<?php 

    header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); 

    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_database = "lalalala";
    $mysql_user = "lalalalal";
    $mysql_password = "lalalallaala";

    if (!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password))
        die("Can't connect to database");

    if (!mysql_select_db($mysql_database))
            die("Can't select database");

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var urlsFinal = [
    <?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM offer_data ORDER BY id_campo DESC");
        while($nt = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    "<?php echo $nt['url']; ?>",
    <?php
        };
    ?>
    "oiasdoiajsdoiasdoiasjdioajsiodjaosdjiaoi.com"
    ];
    scriptLoaded();
});
```

Comment: What is the matter exactly? How is it not VALID? Give the details on the error here.

Comment: What's suppose to happen?

Comment: if your mysql fails, the javascript file will not be valid.

Comment: @epascarello I am using this in an html file using the <script> tag, and need to use the var urlsFinal in some jQuery code included in there. To check if the var is loading or not, I am using alert(urlsFinal[1]) and nothing is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you give it the .php extension

Comment: You need to make sure your HTML script that alerts the var is after this loaded script.

Comment: This would be much less error prone if you generate a php array and then jsonEncode it to a js var.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? What's the expected vs. actual output?

Comment: that's perfectly valid. but you never did anythign with urlsFinal, and since you defined it within that scope and not globally, it is instantly inaccessible to any other piece of code. (i'm referring to the comment you posted a moment ago without the call to `scriptLoaded()`)

Comment: Ok, I've decided to make the question a bit more complete. You can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530364/what-am-i-doing-wrong-loading-this-js-array

Comment: Delete this question since you made another one!

Comment: @epascarello will do. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your Browser to see your PHP file like a `.js` file, `echo` or `print` the entire PHP page into a string, there will be no need to use any headers, just something like:

```
// First let's make a secure page called database.php - put in a restricted folder
<?php
  function db(){
    return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
  }
?>
// now let's go over a new technique you'll cherish in the future - page.php
<?php
include 'restricted/database.php'; $db = db();
if($db->connect_errort)die("Can't connect to database. Error:".$db->connect_errno);
$db->query("UPDATE tabelName SET names='utf8' WHERE column='value'");
$sel = $db->query('SELECT * FROM offer_data ORDER BY id_campo DESC');
if($sel->num_rows > 0){
  while($nt = $db->fetch_object()){
    $output[] = $nt->url;
  }
}
else{
  die('No records were returned.')
}
$sel->free(); $out = implode("', '", $output); $db->close();
echo "jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var urlsFinal = ['$out'];
  // more jQuery here - you may want to escape some jQuery \$ symbols
}"
?>
```

Now just make sure your `script` tag looks like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='page.php'></script>
```

Comment: This approach is however completely pointless (what OP is asking for), yet it's an answer to the question.