# What am I doing wrong loading this js array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I've added another question specifically about what I think is the problem here, but I think a bit more detail will do some good. So, this is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Prueba jQuery no event</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadUrls.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    jQuery("a").click(function(ev) {

        //ev.preventDefault();

        // Defino las variables
        var currentAnchor = jQuery(this);
        var currentHref = currentAnchor.attr('href');
        var curHref = currentHref.split('/');
        var curHrefFinal = curHref[2].replace('www.', '');

        if(jQuery.inArray(curHrefFinal,urlsFinal) > -1) {
            // Evito que se visite el link directo
            ev.preventDefault();

            if (ev.metaKey || ev.ctrlKey) {
                // Redirecciono el navegador a la página que queremos
                window.open(currentHref + "?a=esta-funcionando-tambien");
            } else {
                // Redirecciono el navegador a la página que queremos
                window.location = currentHref + "?a=esta-funcionando";
            };
        };
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Hola, <a href="http://www.avantrip.com">este es</a> un link.</p>
<p>Hola, <a href="http://espana.aula365.com/es/">este es</a> otro link.</p>
<p>Hola, <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">este es</a> otro link.</p>
<p>Hola, <a href="http://www.airborn.com.ar">este es</a> otro link.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The loadUrls.php file is outputting:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var urlsFinal = [
        "avantrip.com.ar",
        "avantrip.com",
        "espana.aula365.com",
        "almashopping.com",
        "airborn.com.ar",
        "1and1.mx",
        "oiasdoiajsdoiasdoiasjdioajsiodjaosdjiaoi.com"
    ];
});
```

Basically, I am comparing the  href attributes of all links being clicked to a array that is being generated dynamically from an SQL database. This array needs to be hosted in an external file, hence the loadUrls.php file.

For some reason, the urlsFinal var is not being recognised in the main code. If I copy the array and paste it in the main file, the rest of the thing is working correctly. I can't find any problems, but I'm sure you will.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add `header(Content-Type: text/javascript);` in your `php` file ?

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 yes, I have.

Comment: Are not you only `echo/printing` the array ?

Comment: You really should think about what $(document).ready() does... you don't need to wrap everything in it.

Comment: Don't forget to vote up the right answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a local scope for the variable -- you should put it into the global scope, by making `loadUrls.php` simply the script (without the `$(document).ready` wrapper):

```
var urlsFinal = [
    "avantrip.com.ar",
    "avantrip.com",
    "espana.aula365.com",
    "almashopping.com",
    "airborn.com.ar",
    "1and1.mx",
    "oiasdoiajsdoiasdoiasjdioajsiodjaosdjiaoi.com"
];
```

An alternative way of adding it to the global scope (if say you needed the `$(document).ready` closure for some other reason), is to use `window.urlsFinal = [ ... ]`.

Comment: That was simple... Thanks!

Comment: +1, if you mention `header(Content-Type: text/javascript);` it would be a good resource for future reference. I doubt it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `urlsFinal` in a global space. There's two ways to do this.

Method 1: Use the `window` variable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var urlsFinal = [
        "avantrip.com.ar",
        "avantrip.com",
        "espana.aula365.com",
        "almashopping.com",
        "airborn.com.ar",
        "1and1.mx",
        "oiasdoiajsdoiasdoiasjdioajsiodjaosdjiaoi.com"
    ];
    window['urlsFinal'] = urlsFinal;
});
```

Method 2: Declare the variable in a global space, but initialize it in the same space.

```
var urlsFinal;
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    urlsFinal = [
        "avantrip.com.ar",
        "avantrip.com",
        "espana.aula365.com",
        "almashopping.com",
        "airborn.com.ar",
        "1and1.mx",
        "oiasdoiajsdoiasdoiasjdioajsiodjaosdjiaoi.com"
    ];
});
```